# Singleton Piece for Settings

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been having a ton of fun using Apostrophe, and I recently ran into a question about the best way to set up some site-wide settings. Is there a way to create a singleton object of some sort, that would function like a piece but only have a single instance?

I'm asking because I'm looking for a way to store site-wide settings in an easily accessible and editable way. Things like global banner images, contact form links that would show up on every page (on the outerLayout), etc. I'd like to be able to leverage built in Apostrophe controls for things like this (like a singleton referencing the page for contact forms, and an image with a set ratio) without having to add a separate custom page to configure these things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be using the global doc, which can be set up to have its own schema

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/settings.html